# Difference between assembly, packages and SDK in ASP.NET Core class library

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dependencies, class-library

I have an old project that runs on ASP.NET Core 2.1. The project has dependencies folder in which we have

- assemblies
- packages(nuget packages)
- SDK

I am little bit confused by their usage and what does dependencies folder mean.

As far I know

- assemblies are .net libraries that referenced into this project and it has a global scope in solution and cant be update until you manually update them.
- nuget packages are installed using nuget package manager and are managed and updated when a new update but nuget package has only project scope.
- sdk is like a set of tools that is used same like nuget package I think.

Here is the screenshot showing the dependencies format

[.net core class library 2.1 Dependecies image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wGy0D.png)

Another thing is that I am creating a new project when I add .net core class library. I have dependecies folder but it's missing

1. assemblies
2. packages(nuget packages)
3. SDK

but it has a new folder called framework

[.net core 3.0 class library dependency image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49Wtn.png)

I think I have to manually add these packages in my project. And what's the difference between these three?

Answer (score 0):

**Assemblies**:- When we compile our source code then assembly gets generated in Visual Studio. Assembly consists of two parts Manifest and IL(Intermediate Language). Manifest contains assembly metadata means assembly's version requirements, security identity, names and hashes of all files that make up the assembly.

**Packages**:- A package is a container for the definitions of UML elements such as classes, use cases, and components. A package can also contain other packages. In UML Model Explorer, all the definitions inside a package are nested underneath the package.

**Nuget Packages**:- NuGet packages are pre-defined pieces of code which are reusable for other developers. You can add a NuGet package to your project and use it's functionality wherever you want in your project. We can also say that NuGet behaves like a platform, where developers can create and share code with the world.

**SDK**:-A SDK(software development kit) is a collection of APIs(Application Programming Interface) that you can reference as a single item in Visual Studio. The Reference Manager dialog box lists all the SDKs that are relevant to the project. When you add an SDK to a project, the APIs are available in Visual Studio.

Packages can not be added manually

here is the link in which it's been clearly explained how to add packages in visual studio:-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/install-and-use-a-package-in-visual-studio